# cannot read property of undefined on data loading

Tags: angular, observable, undefined, async-pipe

authState$ is an Observable variable of type

```
{
    ...
    isAuthenticated: boolean;
    user: User | null;
}
```

User property is initiated on ngrx effect init if the user is authenticated.

the error is that the code below in template return `cannot read property fullName of undifined`

```
<div *ngIf="(this.authState$ | async).isAuthenticated" >
    {{ (this.authState$ | async).user.fullName || '' }}
</div>
```

I tried this solution

```
{{ (this.authState$ | async).user ? (this.authState$ | async).user.fullName : '' }}
```

but it turned out that it doesn't listening for changes and I have to reload the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change it as follows, fewer subscription created this way and div block will not be shows in DOM unless user is authenticated, [safe operator](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths) is the way to get safely check nasty properties:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="authState$ | async as authState">
  <div *ngIf="authState?.isAuthenticated" >
    {{ authState?.user?.fullName || '' }}
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

or keep it as follows:

```
<div *ngIf="(this.authState$ | async)?.isAuthenticated" >
    {{ (this.authState$ | async)?.user?.fullName || '' }}
</div>
```

Although I would also recommend to check why `user` property is not populated for authenticated users